Diamond heist movie or tv movie or series
I've seen a movie or it could be a TV movie or TV series I don't remember. I saw it in the late 90s. I think this movie wasn't very popular, that's why it cannot be found easily. There are some funny parts in the movie too. Here are some scenes:

A man escapes down a building on a rope then two men with bare hands grab the moving rope then their hands are cut and bleed.
A gang or group of people trashes the home of some people to find the diamond.
Diamond was in the Trash can.
A man points a gun on another man then he looks back, then the other man grabs the gun.


A bit of a long shot here, but are you looking for Snatch (2000)? Let me know if this is correct and I'll post a valid answer you can accept.

no it isn't snatch it is from the 1990s. It may be american or canadian.

Found it! It's called Why Me (IMDb, Wikipedia). They were trying to rob diamonds but found a ruby.



